# How to take two or more numbers from a file and add/subtract them

Tags: linux, echo, addition, subtraction

File datestamps:

```
TIME_SETRUN=1517299635
TIME_SUBMIT=1517299661
TIME_EXEC=1517771852
TIME_EXPIRE=1518117452
TIME_FINISHED=1517811003
```

I am a total beginner.

These are some values I found in a file. 
I wanted to add/subtract the number besides TIME_EXEC from that besides TIME_FINISHED. 
How do I do this?

When I try to grab a value by doing `grep TIME_SETRUN file_name`, I get the following result.
`TIME_SETRUN=1517299635`.

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference like this with `bash` and `grep`:

```
(grep -E "TIME_EXEC|TIME_FINISHED" yourfile ; echo 'echo $(( $TIME_FINISHED - $TIME_EXEC ))' ) | bash
```

This uses *one* `grep` to find the two times in one go. Let us ignore the echo part for a moment: The `grep ... | bash` fowards these lines `TIME_EXEC=1517771852` and `TIME_FINISHED=1517811003` into a bash process.

The `echo 'echo $(( $TIME_FINISHED - $TIME_EXEC ))'` forwards the letters inside the quotes, too.

Thus the bash process sees gets three lines forwarded: two definitions of the variables and one line `echo $(( $TIME_FINISHED - $TIME_EXEC ))` which outputs the difference.